# Swap specific values in matrix

Tags: r

A matrix has values ranging from 1-5, and `dim = [1] 3219 10`. What code will be best to swap 3 with 5 and 5 with 3 ?

The dataset has been converted to matrix using

```
[adhd <- as.matrix(original_dataset,replace=TRUE)]
```

Comment: For two values then a nested `ifelse()`  is one way to go about it -  `ifelse(adhd == 3, 5, ifelse(adhd == 5, 3, adhd))`.